# Publish-Subscribe in spring?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, spring-mvc, publish-subscribe

Can any one tell me how to use the Publish-Subscribe pattern in Spring? Does Spring have any built-in functionality to implement this?

In Java we can do like this: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/observer-pattern.html .

Comment: Don't exactly understand the context Anand - let me throw in something. Publish subscribe is a messaging concept and is used for broadcasting a message(or event). Typically this is done in the context of a MOM(Message oriented middleware) system like ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ etc. 

Spring does implement Publish/Subscribe pattern within the "Spring Integration" framework and you can see more details of it here(http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#channel)

Comment: What about the `JMS` in spring . Does `JMS` handles uses the 'Publish-Subscribe' ?

Comment: @Anand Have you considered reading the documentation of Spring Integration? [Messaging](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-integration-core-messaging), [JMS](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#jms)

Comment: there is a distinction between the observer and publish-subscribe.  in observer pattern, the observable is usually aware of the observers because it has to link them.  in publish-subscribe, publishers and subscribers are completely unaware of each other.  this is more complicated so it usually uses complicated things like a message queue service or other middle man.  spring IoC actually can help here, since it can take care of the dependencies between observable and observer and be that middle man (see my comment on the answer).  i think this is a real question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring is Java; obviously you can use any Java pattern in Spring, with the additional benefits of Spring (IoC and AOP in particular). Spring itself [provides its own events](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/observer-pattern-with-spring-events.html) that can be used to do it.

[Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) brings a ton of Java EE patterns to Spring, including Pubsub. It may be a bit heavy for simplistic use cases; something like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) and [Spring's AMQP support](http://digitalsanctum.com/2010/08/31/using-rabbitmq,-spring-amqp-and-spring-integration/) is lighter.

PubSub is just a pattern: there are a *ton* of ways to implement it. Which makes the most sense depends on a lot of factors. Consider searching a bit more on the web before asking such a broad question; there are a ton of resources covering a wide range of implementation choices.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for your answer.ok I will go refer the docs and let you know.

Comment: I found the another way without using any open source  by http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/ImplementsApplicationEventPublisherAware.htm and http://www.lordofthejars.com/2011/10/una-terra-promessa-un-mondo-diverso.html

Comment: @Anand How is that different than Spring's events? And the second link is the exact same text as the link I provided... whatever.

Comment: Yes I got Idea from your link only and that's why I accepted your answer. And special thanks for your golden answer.

Comment: in short, org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher and ApplicationListener